# Why is an AppBar adding squares to the background of my app bar

Tags: android, xml, layout, toolbar, appbar

Good afternoon all,

I have been digging at this for a long time now and its time to ask for help.

I have the following AppBar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_constrained"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/appbar_background_2020">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/appbar_background_2020"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/app_bar_constrained">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="0dp">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_2020"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:elevation="0dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        tools:text="Title" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_sub_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        tools:text="Subtitle"
                        tools:visibility="visible" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="24dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@24dp"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/appbar_background_2020"
            app:tabBackground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:tabGravity="start"
            app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tab_indicator"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="1dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="2dp"
            app:tabPaddingStart="2dp"
            app:tabRippleColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabBar"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="48dp"
            tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="0dp" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The layout renders with a little artifact on the bottom right and bottom left of the toolbar, where the background is curved and clipped:

[image: Toolbar]

I've previously gotten rid of this by using a ConstraintLayout instead of an AppBar, but that does not work with the animations of a CoordinatorLayout, which we are keen to use.

Please note: due to corporate considerations I have had to change colours in the above code sample.

**EDIT:** In answer to the below questions, the background file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="24dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="24dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
    android:topRightRadius="0dp" />

<solid android:color="@color/white" />
```

Comment: You could try setting the elevation to 0?

Comment: Yep, I've tried that. The issue seems to come from the AppBarLayout - if I remove that I can get rid of those little corners.

Comment: You can try setting the background shape to toolbar and making AppBarLayout transparent or invisible?

Comment: No dice. Setting visibility to invisible hides all components, and setting the colour to transparent makes no difference.

Comment: Whats `appbar_background_2020` can you add it with question .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you are using **android:elevation="0dp"** instead of **app:elevation="0dp"** in your AppBarLayout.

Add also in your activity the below code:

```
findViewById(R.id.campfire_app_bar).bringToFront();
```

Comment: When I change `android:elevation` to `app:elevation` the z-order is removed (along with the shadow artefact), leading to the cards underneath scrolling over the top of the toolbar.

Comment: Check my updated answer by adding the bringToFront() on appBar in combination with app:elevation="0dp". If the problem still exists upload a demo project on github to replicate the issue.

Comment: @skooter please share your full code with scrollbar including the cards

Comment: Thanks @MariosP - that worked.
Off to figure out creating my own shadows next.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `AppBar` you can use only `LinearLayout`. I hope this will resolve your problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_constrained"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/appbar_background_2020"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/app_bar_constrained"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="0dp">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_2020"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:elevation="0dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        tools:text="Title" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar_sub_title"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        tools:text="Subtitle"
                        tools:visibility="visible" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:fadingEdgeLength="24dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:elevation="0dp"
            android:background="@drawable/appbar_background_2020"
            app:tabBackground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            app:tabGravity="start"
            app:tabIndicator="@drawable/tab_indicator"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="1dp"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabPaddingEnd="2dp"
            app:tabPaddingStart="2dp"
            app:tabRippleColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorAccent"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabBar"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="48dp"
            tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="0dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Those artifacts are coming from the *AppBarLayout* shadow due to its elevation. (Your layout has all elevations set to `0dp`, but maybe this is not what you are actually using.)

If you need elevation but don't want the shadow then you can specify the following for the *AppBarLayout*:

```
android:outlineProvider="none" // Eliminates the shadow for API 21+. 
                               // Below API 21, there shouldn't be a shadow
android:elevation="2dp"        // Set elevation for API 21+
```

Another thing that may be confusing things: You are overusing your drawable `appbar_background_2020`. I think that you should find the best place for it and only specify it once.

The above will eliminate the shadow but, if you want a shadow that follows the curve of your *AppBarLayout*, that is something that you may be able to resolve with an online search.

Comment: Thanks @Cheticamp. Could you please expand upon the comment about the background Drawable?

Comment: the `outlineProvider` solution doesn't work for the `AppBarLayout`.

Comment: @skooter You are using the background drawable in three places. I was wondering if this is right. I also thought it was defined on the toolbar but it isn't, so it's most likely not an issue.The other stuff was working for me but doesn't now, so not sure what is happening there. I did find that setting `app:elevation` of the AppBar to any value will get rid of the artifacts, so you could just specify `app:elevation="4dp"` to set the default elevation and eliminate the artifacts. I am using material 1.2.1.